# List of Lists, or Dataframe for searching & deleting records?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list

I have imported a CSV file into a List of Lists. ie Normal database.

The actions I need to do on the database is: delete a few records based on field data, & delete duplicates.

I figured converting the List of Lists into a Pandas Dataframe would be easier to work with, however Dataframes seem to be difficult for deleting records.

Is there a Pandas method for searching & deleting records? I've had to iterate via FOR loop, which is apparently NOT good Pandas methodology. I got DF.append() working to fill a 2nd DF with valid records, however I received the "depreciated" message.  I have NOT been able to get pandas.concat() to work correctly for me.  Seems to me that pandas.concat() prefers if I feed it a List of Lists again?

The code segment that I'm building (contains some debug print statements)

`SummaryTable = Read_Control_File(AlarmsCSV)`

##### Convert List of Lists to Dataframe

`Summary_DF = pandas.DataFrame(SummaryTable,` 
`columns=['pair','price','direction',`
`'exch','desc','telegram','discord','email'])`

`print ('Summary DF')`
`print (Summary_DF)`

##### 2nd DF to populate with valid records

Temp_DF = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['pair','price','direction', 
'exch','desc','telegram','discord','email'])

for i in range (0, len(Summary_DF)) :

```
TestPair = Summary_DF.iloc[i]['pair']
if TestPair[:1] != '#' :
    
    print ('Pair without #')
    print (Summary_DF.iloc[i]['pair'])
    print ('DF Row')
    print (Summary_DF.iloc[i])
    Temp_DF = pandas.concat([Temp_DF,Summary_DF.iloc[i]], \
            ignore_index = True)

    print ('Temp DF AFTER Concat')
    print (Temp_DF)
```

`print ('Temp DF')`
`print (Temp_DF)`

`Summary_DF = Temp_DF`

`print ('Summary DF after DROP')`
`print (Summary_DF)`
`` sys.exit()` ``

Database (small enough for inclusion)

Summary DF pair       price direction  ... telegram discord email 0     BTC-USDT       30835         >  ...        x1     BTC-USDT       29660         >  ...        x2     BTC-USDT       23390         <  ...        x3     BTC-USDT       20000         <  ...        x4     BTC-USDT       15000         <  ...        x5     BTC-USDT       12000         <  ...        x6     CRO_USDT       0.073         >  ...        x7     CRO_USDT       0.054         <  ...        x8     CRO_USDT       0.043         <  ...        x9     VVS_USDT  0.00000377         >  ...        x10   #VVS_USDT  0.00000335         <  ...        x11    VVS_USDT  0.00000290         <  ...        x12  #LOKI-USDT        0.11         <  ...        x13  #LOKI-USDT        0.05         <  ...        x14   SCRT-USDT        0.69         >  ...        x15   SCRT-USDT       0.608         >  ...        x16  #SCRT-USDT         0.5         <  ...        x17   SCRT-USDT         0.3         <  ...        x18    HEX-USDT        0.01         <  ...        x19   #PRV-BUSD        0.50         <  ...        x

Even a single record CONCAT... in the FOR LOOP looks bizarre ....

Temp DF AFTER Concat pair price direction exch desc telegram discord email                  0 0   NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN           BTC-USDT 1   NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN              30835 2   NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN                  > 3   NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN            binance 4   NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN       BTC new High ..  ...   ...       ...  ...  ...      ...     ...   ...                ... 75  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN                cdc 76  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN  ABOVE Bottom Band 77  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN                  x 78  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN79  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN   NaN

[80 rows x 9 columns]

I think all is explained previously....

Comment: You shouldn't iterate the rows in place but use vectorization. For instance you loop could be replaced by something like: `out = Summary_DF[~Summary_DF['pair'].str.startswith('#')]`

Comment: I provided this exact logic as comment above, give it a try ;)

Comment: @mozway  OK, I need to learn about vectorization.  However, what I'm trying to do is delete the rows where Summary_DF['pair'] starts with '#'.  You can see that in the code, my line is ....**if TestPair[:1] != '#' : **   Is there a simple way of finding & deleting rows USING vectorization?  Could I use **Summary_DF = Summary_DF.drop(out)** ?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code.  I see my idea of using DF.drop() doesn't work.  However your code DOES work.  Also fascinating/wierd that '~' means 'NOT', rather than '!' .